# Agrupación de datos en una misma tabla

Tags: r

Parto de unos datos parecidos a estos:

```
structure(list(TIPO = c("Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", 
"Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1", "Tipo1"), ANYO = c("2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019"), CURSO = c("curso1", "curso1", 
"curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", 
"curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", 
"curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso1", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", 
"curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", 
"curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", 
"curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", 
"curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", "curso2", 
"curso2", "curso2"), SEXO = c("H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H"), EDAD = c(14, 14, 13, 13, 
12, 12, 14, 12, 14, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 13, 
12, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 
12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 12, 13, 14, 13, 13, 14, 13, 12, 12, 13, 12, 
13)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-53L))
```

Los agrupo,
teniendo en cuenta el sexo

```
datos %>% dplyr::count(TIPO,    ANYO,   CURSO,  SEXO,   EDAD) -> tabla1
```

y sin tenerlo en cuenta

```
datos %>% dplyr::count(TIPO,    ANYO,   CURSO,  EDAD) -> tabla2
```

Quiero obtener el valor maximo por grupo y dividirlo entre el total (con y sin sexo)

```
tabla1 %>% group_by( TIPO,  ANYO,   CURSO,  SEXO) %>%
  mutate(tasa_sexo = round((max(n) /sum(n)*100),2)) -> T1

tabla2 %>% group_by(TIPO,   ANYO,   CURSO) %>%
  mutate(tasa = round((max(n) /sum(n)*100),2)) -> T2
```

Hago lo mismo en excel para comprobar que salen los mismos porcentajes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es esto mismo pero que los dos resultados salgan en una misma tabla.

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes las dos sumatorias puedes relacionarlas mediante algún tipo de `join`, por ejemplo:

```
datos %>%
  count(TIPO, ANYO, CURSO, SEXO, EDAD) %>% 
  group_by(TIPO, ANYO, CURSO, SEXO) %>% 
  mutate(max_tasa_sexo = max(round(n/sum(n)*100,2))) %>% 
  left_join(datos %>% 
              count(TIPO, ANYO, CURSO, EDAD) %>% 
              group_by(TIPO, ANYO, CURSO) %>% 
              summarize(max_tasa = max(round(n/sum(n)*100,2)),
                        .groups = "drop_last"),
            by = c("TIPO", "ANYO", "CURSO")
  )

# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   TIPO, ANYO, CURSO, SEXO [3]
  TIPO  ANYO  CURSO  SEXO   EDAD     n max_tasa_sexo max_tasa
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <int>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Tipo1 2019  curso1 H        12     5          45.4     40  
2 Tipo1 2019  curso1 H        13     2          45.4     40  
3 Tipo1 2019  curso1 H        14     4          45.4     40  
4 Tipo1 2019  curso1 M        12     3          66.7     40  
5 Tipo1 2019  curso1 M        13     6          66.7     40  
6 Tipo1 2019  curso2 H        12     9          39.4     39.4
7 Tipo1 2019  curso2 H        13    13          39.4     39.4
8 Tipo1 2019  curso2 H        14    11          39.4     39.4
```